# A flexible function to upload images in PHP

Tags: php

I have created a function that I use to upload my images in PHP

```
<?php
function addImage($imageWidthRequired, $imageHeightRequired) {

    if (file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) || is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        $imageSize = @getimagesize($_FILES['image']["tmp_name"]);

        $imageWidth = $imageSize['0'];
        $imageHeight = $imageSize['1'];

        if ($imageWidth == $imageWidthRequired && $imageHeight == $imageHeightRequired) {

            //Perform an action
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Everything works fine but I am now facing a problem. I want the user to be able to upload an image without specifying the required dimensions `$imageWidthRequired` and `$imageHeightRequired`. That means that the user can upload any dimension of image.

Kindly help me get some ideas to make this functions flexible and allow the user to uploas a file without specifying the required measurements. Thanks

Comment: And what do you want from us?

Comment: Some ideas to get to my aim, if possible

Comment: `function addImage()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set some default parameters for `$imageWidthRequired` and `$imageHeightRequired` (like NULL) in the function definition and check if the values provided are NULL or something else before proceeding.

```
<?php

function addImage($imageWidthRequired = null, $imageHeightRequired = null) {
    if ($imageWidthRequired == null && $imageHeightRequired == null) {
        // image dimensions are not provided
    } else {
        // image dimensions are provided.
    }
}
```

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski What kind of a scripted comment is that? The author asked for suggestions how to solve a problem and I provided one. This is critique nor a request for clarification.